# Syntax Error: missing ) after argument list @(shell):2:4

Tags: mongodb

I am getting the above error in Mongo DB when entering the following in the shell but I can't for the life of me see where there is a syntax error...

```
db.createUser (
... "user":"dbTest",
... "pwd":"testPass",
... "roles": [
... { "role":"readWrite", "db":"test" }
... ]
... )
```

That has been copied and pasted directly from the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing curly braces around the object literal:

```
db.createUser ({
    "user":"dbTest",
    "pwd":"testPass",
    "roles": [
    { "role":"readWrite", "db":"test" }
    ]
    })
```

See [`db.createUser()` - Examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/#examples)

Comment: I get the same error when running `rocky26 = Movie.create(title:  "Rocky XXVI")` I tried passing `{ }` and still didn't work. According to the documentation that is the right way to do it. `Model.create`

Comment: @StevenAguilar I'm sure you have figured it out by now but I think you should have had `Movie.create({"title": "Rocky XXVI"})`